# Modify an imported framework source code

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to add this [library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to my project without using Pods. I also want to be able to modify its source code. In their [git](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1474) they explain that the most suitable way to do it is to drag the Charts.xcodeproj file to the project:

> Yes you can copy it the classes like before. However it's more
>   comfortable to drag the xcodeproj to the project. It's not recommended
>   to drag the sources themselves, as this will make updating Chrats in
>   your project more difficult.

I added the xcodeproj file to my project, compiled it and added it to `My Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`. When I build the project the app crashed with a `signal SIGABRT` error. I googled the problem and than I added the `Charts.framework` in `General -> Embedded Binaries`. The App compiled and worked fine after that but modifying the source code in `Charts.xcodeproj -> Charts -> Source` dose not have any effect on the library. I am confused. How can I add the library to my project in a way that other people will not have to do it again when they download the project, and also to be able to modify the project source code?

Comment: no need to do that also if you just want the source code which you can use and change then download github proect and in source folder copy charts folder.

Comment: Just copy the source folder in your project and use it

Comment: I think the Framework is written in swift 4.0 and I am using swift 3

Comment: Try to download this : https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/c8ae3ea2f5c844a6778efed685768105a6d06b39

Comment: I got errors like "Cannot use instance member '_viewPortHandler' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" on some classes of the framework. It's probably because of the swift version.